# Invalidating NSTimer not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that is set up for 150 seconds, and when it gets down to 0, it should stop counting and end the game I'm creating. But, when I call the invalidate() it will just keep going. I also have it so that it should print "Timer stopped" when the timer is invalidated but no luck. Is there another way to to this?

Here is my code:

```
import SpriteKit
var countDown: NSTimer()

class GameScene: SKScene {
  override func didMoveToView(view:SKView)
   countDown = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "subtractTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
 override func update() {
  if countDown == 0 {
      countDown.invalidate()
       print("Timer stopped")
     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you compare `countDown` with `Int` value. If you need invalidate timer when it's fired - do it inside `subtractTime` method.

You also mentioned that you setup your timer for `150` seconds. But in code example it is `1.0`. So I suggest you want your selector be called 150 times with one second delay. If so, you could simply add counter variable:

```
var counter = 0
...
func subtractTime() {
  counter += 1
  if counter == 150 {
    countDown.invalidate()
    countDown = nil // also add this line to escape retain cycle
    return
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Ill try try this out and give you some feedback!

Comment: So when I add the countDown = nil, I get an error that says "Cannot assign a value of type NilLiteralConvertable to a value of type "NSTimer"

Comment: Never mind! I fixed it and it works perfectly! Thanks a bunch!!